# Remove duplicate objects from array using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, duplicates

i have an  array of object menuProduitSet[] , 
after pushing to it 'menuProduit' which  is object of object 
how can in remove duplicate objects ???

```
var menuProduitSet = [];
        $('select').children('optgroup').children('option:selected').each(function () {
        var ch = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().attr('class').substring(4, 5);
                   if (ch !== 'undefined') {
                       if (ch !== 'c') {
                            var produit = {"prodId": $(this).val()};
                            var menuProduit = {menuProduitPK: {menu: menu["menuId"], produit: produit["prodId"], choix: ch}, menu: {menuId: menu["menuId"]}, produit: {prodId: produit["prodId"]}};
                            menuProduitSet.push(menuProduit);
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218999/remove-duplicates-from-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript

Comment: not working because i have 3 objects in one object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend if you can use Javascript libraries such as underscore or lodash, look at *.uniq function.*
.uniq - Underscore.js - 
[_.uniq - Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#uniq)

So when you have the final array(menuProduitSet):

```
// by menu.menuId:
var byMenuId = _.uniq(menuProduitSet, function(m){ return m.menu.menuId; }); 

// by produit.prodId 
var byProdId = _.uniq(menuProduitSet, function(m){ return m.produit.prodId; });
```